# Is there a way to sum and multiply rationals of the form $z/2$, $z \in \mathbb Z$ to obtain a rational with a denominator that is not a power of $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Is there a way to sum and multiply elements of $(1/2)\mathbb Z$ to obtain a rational number with a denominator that is not a power of $2$?

An explicit characterization of $(1/2)\mathbb Z$ is $\{ \frac{z}{2}: z \in \mathbb Z\}$. I'm thinking the answer to the above question is most likely no, and I show my work through the following argument:

**Work/Proof/Argument.** Let $r$ be the result of sums and products between elements of $(1/2)\mathbb Z$. Then $r$ is the sum of simple terms $s_i = z_i/2$ with nonsimple terms $s'_i$, which are products of sums of simple terms.

Notice: any sums $\sum s_i$ of simple terms $s_i$ will be equivalent to an irreducible fraction with denominator 1 or 2. Therefore, any products $s'_i$ of $\sum s_i$ will have as a denominator a power of $2$.

Let $T$ be the nonsimple term of $r$ with the greatest denominator, and set all other terms to the same denominator. Then, $r$ is a fraction that has a denominator that is a power of $2$. If this fraction is irreducible, we are done. If it is reducible, then the numerator and denominator of $q$ have a nontrivial greatest common denominator, and since any divisor of a power of $2$ must be a power of $2$, the resulting irreducible fraction has as a denominator a power of $2$. $\square$

Alternatively, are there more succinct ways of arguing? I've been learning commutative algebra lately, maybe there is a more algebraic argument available?

Comment: Re: "more algebraic argument" - it's a special case of [localization.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra))

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for your comment. I've thought a bit more on this after reading Robert Shore's argument, does the general form of such arguments consist in showing $\{\frac{p}{q}: 2 \nmid p; q = 2^n; n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a ring?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational#In_advanced_mathematics) for the localization view of these *dyadic rationals*.

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you, very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.  The easiest way to see it is by induction on the number of terms in the sum or product.

Assume $x=\dfrac {r}{2^m}, y=\dfrac{s}{2^n}$, with $x, y$ odd integers, $m, n \in \Bbb N$. Interchanging terms if necessary, we can assume $m \leq n$.  Then $xy=\dfrac{rs}{2^{m+n}}, x+y=\dfrac{2^{n-m}r+s}{2^n}.$  Thus, any sum or product of two fractions whose denominators are powers of two is again a fraction whose denominator is a power of two.

To prove the result for arbitrary sums or products, proceed by induction on the number of terms in the sum or product.  This proves $\{ \frac pq \mid 2 \nmid p, q=2^n, n \in \Bbb N \}$ is a ring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Using the idea of showing that last mentioned set is a ring, could we argue also that $(1/2)\mathbb Z \subseteq \{\frac{z}{2^n}: z \in \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb n\} \subseteq \mathbb Q$ and use the subring test?